# updating x-editable input field based on returned value

Tags: javascript, x-editable

in my x-editable field I have a textarea that I want to update based on the returned value. This works when I use `$(this).html(newVal);` as shown below

```
success: function(response, newValue) {
  newVal=unescape(JSON.parse(response).VALUE)
  $(this).html(newVal);
}
```

**the problem is when I click to edit the field the second time, the value inside the input object (class: `editable-input`) stays the same as it was when it was sent.**  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the simplest way:

```
        $('.textarea').editable({
            success: function(response, newValue) {
                    return {newValue: response.newValue};
                }
            }
        });
```

remember to return newValue variable in response content:

```
{"newValue":"some_string_new_value"}
```

Comment: I have the same issue but I want to change the value of the field programmatically. Everything looks like until I click to edit the value; the old one shows up.

Answer (score 2):

this worked. I'm setting the value by calling this function in the `on success` callback

```
  function formatXEditable($item, $val){
    $val = $val.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,"\n");
    $($item).on('shown', function(e, editable) {
      editable.input.$input.val($val);
    });
  }
```

Comment: look on my answer above