# X-Editable update field label dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, x-editable

I'm filling the anchor text (label) of several text fields through an .ajax POST request and by using .html() .

By using the following line I can fill the label of the "title" field dynamically:

```
$("a#title").html(JSONObject[0]);
```

The title field is:

```
<td>title</td>
<td><a href="#" id="title" data-type="text" data-pk="1">foo</a></td>
```

So even though it gets updated with the contents of JSONObject[0], if I click on it to edit it, I still get "foo". 
Is there a way to update that as well?

This is my X-Editable configuration:

```
$('#editform a').editable({
                pk: 1,
                showbuttons: false,
                onblur: 'ignore',
                send: 'never',
                success: function(params) {
                    return false;
                }
            }).editable('show');
```

Using inline and Bootstrap3.

Comment: I also found these:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366436/updating-x-editable-input-field-based-on-returned-value
https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/128

I guess I can't use them because I have set success to false (I want to submit the form only once). 
I tried but it didn't work.